# Does the Developer edition of SQL Server let you have multiple users?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know if the 2008 Developer edition of SQL Server allows you to have multiple developers access it on the same server? I called Microsoft, but the guy I talked to didn't seem to know the answer. Has anyone tried it?

I am a developer that uses the Express edition now on one server and all four of our developers use it in our LAN. If the Developer edition allows me to do the same thing, but with all the extra features of Enterprise, then for $50 I'll buy it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - the Developer edition is really just the Enterprise edition without the licensing rights to use it in production or roll it out in a system. But it's a full-fledged SQL Server, which supports concurrent users and tons of databases on a single server.

Every dev can have their own database (e.g. APP_JOE, APP_PETE, APP_SCOTT etc.) or they can access a common development database - whatever strikes your fancy.

Answer (score 4):

Each person using it needs to have a license, I believe, but there is no technical limitation on allowing other users access to it.

Comment: MSDN ?? Not a Visual Studio license (which they most likely have)?

Comment: Yes -- you need a license specifically for the developer edition. That isn't included in most versions of VS -- though it is with some of the Team editions.  MSDN would certainly suffice.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the Developer Edition of SQL Server is functionally equivalent to Enterprise, but only licensed for Development work, not production.  It should behave like the Enterprise edition, including allowing access by multiple users/applications.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to read the license agreement to be sure, but if memory serves, it says you can have up to 10 concurrent users.